# Why Eclipse null analysis ignore null-checking statement: if (someObject != null) {...}, when someObject is a field-scope variable?

Tags: java, eclipse, null

I have a class like this:

```
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
public class Nullness {

    private @Nullable Object someObject;

    public void foo() {
        if (someObject != null) {
            someObject.toString(); //error "Potential null pointer access: The field someObject is specified as @Nullable"
        }
    }
}
```

And when enable eclipse null analysis, an error is marked at the statement `someObject.toString();` which reads `Potential null pointer access: The field someObject is specified as @Nullable`.

Eclipse has a quick fix that can change my code to be like this:

```
    public void foo() {
        final Object someObject2 = someObject;
        if (someObject2 != null) {
            someObject2.toString();
        } 
    }
```

which can wipe out the error, note that, actually, the `final` modifier is not required to make the error disappear.

I don't understand why Eclipse does not allow me to use field variable directly in null-checking statement `if (someObject != null)` but force me to create additional local variable `someObject2`. Is this behavior just a bug or it is intended?

Comment: Without me knowing alot about `Nullable` my 6th sense tells me this is what causes the confusion in the compiler. `someObject2` is not `@Nullable`, which seems like the only difference between the two => thats the issue

Comment: @hewo I try marking the `someObject2` with `@Nullable` as well but doesn't cause any error.

Comment: I don't know if this warning is really something you should concider that seriously. You can do `@SuppressWarnings("null pointer")` (or something) to just ignore it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Must apologize the community by posting the question without doing carefully research. This issue is clearly mention in [this wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis/Options#Lenient_analysis), which discuss that using field variable directly can cause unexpected effect in several ways.